# PostgreSQL na hora de criar as tabelas e colunas. OBS: Versão 11.5, ultima versão do PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, java-ee

Galera é o seguinte, quando vou criar as tabelas e colunas no postgreSQL usando pgAdmin4, quando eu crio as tabelas , eles salva o nome dela e o nome do campo entre "". exemplo: 
[image: Tabela e coluna salva com ""]

Como vocêS vêem na imagem, as colunas e tabelas estão entre "", no java quando coloco na minha variavel sql o nome da tabela eu preciso por assim:
String sql = "insert into \"Usuario\"(\"Nome\", \"DataNascimento\", \"Apelido\", \"Email\", \"Senha\", \"Imagem\", \"Genero\", \"SobreNome\") "
                + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
Para vocês verem como fica até dificil a leitura, eu preciso por dessa forma para que o java reconheça a tabela e a coluna do postgreSQL. Seu eu usar uma consulta SQL complexa, a leitura não será boa, alguem sabe onde posso ajeitar isso no PostgreSQL, qual configuração precisa fazer ? versão do postgreSQL que to usando é a ultima 11.5

Comment: Isto é uma característica do pgAdmin. Utilize o psql que não será obrigado a colocar entre aspas, a menos que assim o deseje. Sem utilizar aspas todas as letras são tratadas como minúsculas mas se colocar entre aspas então terá que respeitar a caixa utilizada na definição do nome do campo/tabela.

Comment: Outra possibilidade de solução é criar todos os identificadores com letras minúsculas, neste caso você não precisará utilizar aspas em sua aplicação.

Comment: Já consgui resolver, o negocio é criar as tabelas e colunas com letras minúsculas que não salva com essas "".  Isso é a versão atual do postgreSQL que quando você salva com alguma letrar em maiúscula ele salva a tabela "Pessoa"

Comment: Note que esta característica não é do PostgreSQL, que sempre converte as letras dos identificadores para minúscula, a menos que estejam entre aspas (delimited identifier ou quoted identifier). A inclusão de aspas em qualquer situação é uma característica do cliente PgAdmin e não do PostgreSQL. Outros clientes não agem desta forma.